# How to display div based on selected multiselect

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I am trying to show/hide elements based on multiselect dropdown, but my code doesn't seem to work. For example, one of the data for nameList is Name, and when Name is selected, I would like to display a div with another drop-down menu. I am using Angular and Typescript. Below are my codes for your reference:

```
<kendo-multiselect [data]="nameList" [(ngModel)]="selectedname "></kendo-multiselect>


<div *ngIf="selectedname === 'Name'">
<div class="col-4">
   You selected {{selectedname}}
</div>
<div class="col-2">Name:</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <kendo-dropdownlist style="width: 100%" [data]="anotherList" [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, can you put the `You selected {{selectedname}}` line outside the if, and just below the first `kendo-multiselect` and show me the output? You are treating like the `selectedname` will be a string, but I suspect its an Object since it doesnt have to store only one name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically here `selectedname` returns an array, so you need to check whether an item exists in an array or not. So you can use the below code to check -

```
<kendo-multiselect [data]="nameList" [(ngModel)]="selectedname "></kendo-multiselect>


<div *ngIf="isShown('Name')">
<div class="col-4">
   You selected {{selectedname}}
</div>
<div class="col-2">Name:</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <kendo-dropdownlist style="width: 100%" [data]="anotherList" [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>
</div>


isShown(flag) {
      console.log(this.selectedname.indexOf(flag));
      if (this.selectedname.indexOf(flag) !== -1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5njzks?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: haha this mean you check this after almost 1 Year, Amazing :D

Comment: Actually, no. Your answer was helpful but during that time, I didn't know that I need to accept an answer. So recently (on last November), I was actually going Stack Overflow and realized that accepting an answer would be helpful for the others. Sorry for the misunderstanding, but really :( @Pardeep Jain

Answer (score 1):

On change event of "kendo-mutliselecet" push selectedname item to "anotherList" then set kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)] to this selectedname.

```
<div *ngIf="selectedname.indexOf('Name')>=0">
```

I think it will be solution.  Not tested.